# R/Shiny DT datatable Search Highlight not working on IE

Tags: r, internet-explorer, datatable, shiny, dt

I have a Shiny app that is working properly in Chrome but not in IE.

In the DT::datatable call I use the option searchHighlight = TRUE. In chrome, when i input some text in the search file of the dataTable, the text is filtered and the matches highlighted. If I open the app on IE I have behaviors that are not consistent. Sometimes the text is highlighted, sometime doesn't. The filtering of the content according to the search seems to work on both the browser.

Anyone's experienced a similar issue?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't had this particular issue, but have experienced different functionality between Chrome and IE in the past in DT. If you haven't already, I would encourage you to raise an issue on github (https://github.com/rstudio/DT/issues) as the rstudio team are really good at looking in to these and getting them resolved.